# Why does composer complain about the ext-mongo extension?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, doctrine-odm

When I try to install doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle and doctrine/mongodb with composer it throws an error.

```sh
composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle doctrine/mongodb
```

```sh
Using version ^3.5 for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
Using version ^1.6 for doctrine/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.6.3 requires ext-mongo ^1.6.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.6.2 requires ext-mongo ^1.6.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.6.1 requires ext-mongo ^1.6.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.6.0 requires ext-mongo ^1.6.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb ^1.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - 
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mongodb.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-soap.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I was suprised to see this error message because I did install Mongodb with pecl and enabled it with an ini file.

```
RUN pecl install mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured that by adding a provide section with the ext-mongo to the composer.json file the issue was resolved

```
"provide" : {
    "ext-mongo": "*"
}
```

It appears to completely ignore the php extension.

Comment: You have installed *mongodb* in your container. Isn't it different from *mongo*?

Comment: Older versions of the extension where called mongo e.g. `php5.6-mongo`. For newer versions they use the full mongodb name.

Comment: This worked for me: "provide" : {
        "ext-mongodb": "*"
    }